# How to call SmtpSection in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, smtp

I learn to send mail in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

Because I didn't see `web.config` in .NET 6 so I create a `web.config` myself and added a `SmtpSection` like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <!--
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
    -->
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="abc@gmail.com">
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="abc@gmail.com" password="jirhklutcubguuul" defaultCredentials="true"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Then I call in controller but it get an error:

```
SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)configurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
```

The error is in SmtpSection (both):

> Error CS0246
> The type or namespace name 'SmtpSection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're missing a `using System.Net.Configuration;`

Comment: I don't know but I can't use System.Net.Configuration. It have an error :The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) @Cid

Comment: System.Net.Configuration is no longer supported in net core, as explained here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33523#issuecomment-598999154

Answer (score 0):

> Because I didn't see web.config in .NET 6 so I create a web.config
> myself and added a SmtpSection. Then I call in controller but it get
> an error:

No, you will not get `web.config` since the asp.net core xxx version. Instead you should keep your configuration credentials in `appsettings.json` file which has introduced in asp.net core.

In order to configure your SMTP credentials, you should write your information in appsettings.json file in key-value pairs. On top of this, you would need a class file for building your configuration and that need to register within program.cs file. Finally, you can call your configuration anywhere from your application when you want to read the configuration values.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can implement that in asp.net core or .NET 6.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "SmtpConfiguration": {
    "From": "abc@gmail.com",
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "Username": "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password": "jirhklutcubguuul",
    "defaultCredentials" : "true"
  }
}
```

SMTP Configuration class:

```
public class SmtpConfigurationClass
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string SmtpServer { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string defaultCredentials { get; set; }
    }
```

Register Configuration In Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//SMTP Configuration

var emailConfig = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection("SmtpConfiguration")
        .Get<SmtpConfigurationClass>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Load Configuration In Controller:

```
public class SMTPClientController : Controller
    {

        private readonly SmtpConfigurationClass _smtpConfig;
        public SMTPClientController(SmtpConfigurationClass smtpClientConfig)
        {
            _smtpConfig = smtpClientConfig;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var getConfiguration = _smtpConfig;
            //Call your SMTP server and pass the credentials from configuration
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#combining-service-collection), if you need more information.